# Adding Rows in a QTreeWidget in runtime messes up widgetItems visuals

Tags: qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I have a `QDialog` show a `QTreeWidget` that has the parameters of some objects.

I have added a button to add extra fields in the vectors of the objects visually like this.

```
void on_Create_Surface_Pressed()
{
  QPushButton * const button = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender());

  QTreeWidgetItem*  branch = treeButtons[button];
  if(branch)
    {
      QTreeWidgetItem* leaf = new QTreeWidgetItem(branch);

      QString str("Point ");
      str+=QString::number(branch->childCount()-1);
      QLabel* label = new QLabel(str); 

      QString surfType[3] = {QString("x") , QString("y") ,QString("z")};
      QTableWidget* surfTable =   sampleTree( surfType);<--(Create and add a
                                                           Table under the 
                                                           qtreewidgetItem)  
      leaf->treeWidget()->setItemWidget(leaf , 0 , label);
      leaf->treeWidget()->setItemWidget(leaf , 1 , surfTable);

      update();
    }
}
```

My problem is that the new rows are rendered above the next `QTreeWidgetItem` until the user collapses the tree(which is the gimmick i m using).

Is there a workaround for this? Or isn't `QTreeWidget` purposed for this use and a `QTreeView` would serve better?

Comment: what does `sampleTree` do exactly ? and what is the parent of the `QTableWidget`. It looks ok in general. So maybe `sampleTree` does something.

Comment: It works fine but I just have the rendering issue until I refresh manually the tree,and I wanted to know if its a known issue.
The sampleTree gets a QString[] and returns a table with the given values to the one column and QLineEdits with QDoublevalidator initialized at 0.00 to the other

Comment: Just for completions sake you should add it to the question if it is not too long. Well rerendering seems something is "not fine" there (I just don't see what currentl). "Known issue" is really hard to say. I don't know it and if you haven't found anything in the Qt bug reports then no. Usually everytime Qt had some rendering issues for me it was because of wrong usage of mine.

Comment: yeh propably this is my first project on qt so I guess I messed somewhere